# how to use session in grails

Tags: session, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am new to grails. And I have to work with session. I have seen the session documentation. But no idea where to put the code in my controller. I have a page for student creation names createStudent. Now I want that this page only be access able when the user will be in session. Now how can I do it. Should I have to set the user in a variable at the time of login. Can anyone please help me on this ?

```
def index() {
    def user = session["user"]
    if (user){
        redirect(controller: 'admistratorAction', action: 'createUser')
    }else{
        redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'index')
    }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `session.getAttribute(key)` and `session.setAttribute(key, value)` methods inside your controller. Alternatively, there are plugins such as the [Spring Security Core Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) that already handle this very well.

There's a good tutorial by Peter Ledbrook for the Spring Security plugin [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auwML_bsUEE) and the plugin documentation links to at least one other tutorial.

** Edit **

As you suggested, in order to use the session directly the user would need to be set in the session at an earlier point. For example:

```
def setCurrentStudent() {
    def aStudent = [name: "Student1"]
    session["user"] = aStudent
    render "Added $aStudent to the session."
}
```

Spring Security will do this automatically at login. Then, the current user can then be accessed at any time using the springSecurityService.

```
class SomeController {
   def springSecurityService
   def someAction = {
       def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
       …
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am already using spring security core plugin. But I don't know how to use session from it. I am giving a sample source code in the editor. It redirect to login page if condition false. but does not redirect createUser page if true. Can you help now ?!

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the problem - why do you need to use the session directly? I've updated my answer with some code snippets. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @osborp it helps for now. I will work on details of session later. But right now this is the answer for the basic

Comment: Thanks for reply. It helps me!