# How to skip login page if user is already logged

Tags: grails, groovy

**Hi iam new to grails, iam trying to skip userlogin if user is already logged**

Is there any suggestions to do (with out Adding Plugins)

Thanking in advance

Comment: What version of spring-security/grails are you using?

Comment: Hi @mahesh, look at this [how-to-use-session-in-grails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387895/5813861)

Comment: Thanks for reply...Is there any possibility do with out use PLUGIN @erichelgeson

Comment: You havent said how you've setup your app so it's impossible to tell. Please add more details on what you have setup and what you'd like to happen and someone may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for Your  valuable Time , Iam using Grails 2.4.4 version , actually I want to skip userLogin if User is already logged @erichelgeson